# Get-iplayer stopped working

Tags: 12.04, get-iplayer

get-iplayer is a really handy script that lets you download BBC programs so you can watch them later.

Recently it's just stopped fetching programs, emitting errors like:

```
ERROR: RTMP_ReadPacket, failed to read RTMP packet header
INFO: Command exit code 1 (raw code = 256)
```

Is this the end of it or is there a fix/update? I'm on Precise LTS so the package is probably not the latest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same issue and resolved it as follows:

I installed `flvstreamer`.  After this `get-iplayer` was able to download!

By the way, don't forget to use `get_iplayer` command NOT `get-iplayer`.